# vector space of all polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ has dimension $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be some field and define $\mathbb{P}$ to be the vector space of all polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{F}$.

**Prove** that $dim(\mathbb{P})=n$.

I tried to take the standard base $B=\{1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}\subset\mathbb{P}$ ,it's clear that $B$ is a spanning set of $\mathbb{P}$.

For linear independence: I took $g=\lambda_1+\lambda_2\cdot x+\cdots+\lambda_n\cdot x^{n-1}=0$.

If $|\mathbb{F}|=\infty$, $g$ has infinitely many roots so it must be the zero polynomial.

If $|\mathbb{F}|\lt\infty$ I don't know.

Comment: The eguagliance that you get from the linear dependence equation is an identity of polynomials, so it should be immediate to say that every coefficient is zero. If you don't want to follow this way, you can always discuss the number of roots like you were doing, keeping in mind that Ruffini rule works on every field (also more..)

Comment: What you are considering is not an identity between polynomial functions, but between polynomials. When two polynomials are equal?